# How to assign a value to a new button

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  btn = $("<button>");
  btn.attr("class", "btn");
  btn.attr("value", animals[i]);
  btn.text(celebrities[i]);
  console.log(btn.value);
  $("#animals").append(btn);
  }
```

Console logging btn.value returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: jQuery objects don’t have a `value` property. Read the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Use `console.log(btn.val())` for an Element's `.value` in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Button don't have value attribute, use can use data-value to set attribute for button like this. Also you wrong format `btn = $("<button>");`

```
btn = $("button");
btn.attr("class", "btn");
btn.attr("data-value", "Test Value");
btn.text("Text");
console.log(btn.text());
console.log(btn.data("value"));
```

```js
btn = $("button");
btn.attr("class", "btn");
btn.attr("data-value", "Test Value");
btn.text("Text");
console.log(btn.text());
console.log(btn.data("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this is pure JS follow the below steps.

1) Create an element using the createElement function of the document. this function through you can create any king of HTML/OWN element

2) user setAttribute function for setting the attribute

3) Append element into the parent element of the document

```
var animals = ['tiger','dingo','panther']
var celebrities = ['cel1 1','cel 2','cel 3']
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.setAttribute("class", "btn");
  //btn.setAttribute("onclick","clickfunction");
  btn.setAttribute("value", animals[i]);
  btn.innderText  = celebrities[i];
  console.log(btn.value);
  document.getElementById("animals").append(btn);
}
```